# Complex select query, average time series by DAY, use days that average 0 as criteria in another select

Tags: mysql, datetime, time-series

I am not a super-advanced MySQL user, and so I have turned to SO for some help.

What I am trying to accomplish is this:

I have a table called `inodes_data`. I am trying to Average a column called `sens2` where `i_id` is equal to `19371` also where `Time` is between `'20140601' AND '20140831'`...

Here is my problem. I need to include rows only from DAYS (as in midnight to 11:59PM) that the DAILY average of another `I_ID` (`99101`) from the same `inodes_data` table is equal to `0`...

I apologize if this is poorly explained, as I am finding it hard to describe.

Comment: Please provide schema and sample data...

Comment: ... And the desired result based upon that sample

Comment: to sum up the previous two comments just read [**MY POST**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2733506) on how to formulate an appropriate question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pretty much translate your question directly into a MySQL statement, as follows:

```
select avg(sens2)
from inodes_data id
where time between '20140601' and '20140831' and
      i_id = 19371 and
      date(time) in (select date(time)
                    from inodex_data id2
                    where i_id = 99101
                    group by date(time)
                    having avg(sens2) = 0
                   );
```

Often, explicit joins perform better than `in`, so you should use this version:

```
select avg(sens2)
from inodes_data id join
     (select date(time) as d
      from inodex_data id2
      where i_id = 99101
      group by date(time)
      having avg(sens2) = 0
     ) d99101
     on date(id.time) = d99101.d
where time between '20140601' and '20140831' and
      i_id = 19371;
```

Comment: Like it. You may get better performance by changing the `ON` clause to `ON id.time >= d99101.d AND id.time < d99101.d + INTERVAL 1 DAY` allowing the index to be used.

Comment: Testing this out and spot checking the results, but I feel like this is exactly what I was looking for. Will accept shortly if so. Thanks a million.